# Stuck on black screen asking for login and password

Tags: drivers, upgrade, updates

So I tried to update my machine and then a power outage occurred , I googled it and searched around and it told me to hold shift, I got this special menu and clicked advanced options or something (kinda like a system restore) and now it's on a black screen asking for a login? Even though I know my user name and password but it's saying it's incorrect?

Comment: This 'black screen' you're talking about is identical to a terminal right? it asks for your username (remember when you first installed Ubuntu? it's a lower cased single word with no spaces) and then the password you set for it. Tell me if you are able to login using your username and password, then I'm able to write an answer for you.

Comment: Yes. The user name I use to log into my machine is just my name ? As when it used to work it had my name and it asked for my password..

Comment: So regardless of having a correct username you are unable to login because it prompts back 'incoprrect password' right?

Comment: Yes , and when I type in the password field it shows nothing being typed

Comment: This is identical to a Terminal window, when you type your password it would show nothing back. Try filling in your password regardless of is being a white space followed by pressing enter

Comment: There is literally nothing when I type it in, nothing, and also even when I do type it in it says it is wrong, I can not boot into recovery mode without the login / password , I am due to throw my computer out a window

Comment: You can try logging in with username ubuntu and password ubuntu. I'll try to craft an answer in the meanwhile.

Comment: Are you even able to start your machine in a normal manner? usually that is enough to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Nope that didn't work , still saying "login incorrect"

Comment: & no my machine won't boot as an update failed and it goes straight to a black screen, thus the reason I'm doing this

Comment: In that case, try boot repair. If you have another computer you can burn boot repair to a CDROM, or use a LiveUSB. More details here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: This is so stupid, why on earth would you have to input your password for your a recovery? This is too much hassle. Seriously considering going back to Windows

Comment: Your password is required because Linux needs root access in order to modify system files.

Comment: And I know my password, it's the same password I use for my Facebook, Instagram etc. There's virtually no way I could forget it, it is asking for the login

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Use boot repair.

Ubuntu was unable to boot and there is this fancy tool for such problems: [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). This should allow you to boot into Ubuntu again.

Option 2: Reinstall Ubuntu (you are likely to keep your personal files in the Home folder!

You can try writing either a new disk image or live USB with the version of Ubuntu you like, or use the same liveusb/DVDROM you used before and run the distribution update again. You will have the option to keep your home folder (if the hard disk is not corrupt.)